# .text() returns duplicate data in JSON success function

Tags: jquery, json, api, for-loop, each

**Situation:** I've requested JSON data from SmartRecruiters API and appended it into my layout. Becuase the job description is so long, I would like to limit the number of characters within the `p` to x# of characters. After research I worked with `.text()` and concluded to this:

```
var desc = $('.desc')
desc.text(desc.text().substring(0,250) + '...');
console.log("work");
```

The code successfully limits the number of characters but returns duplicate JSON data for each post in the description.

**What I've tried:**

1. I figured it had something to do with the code being included within the `showDetails` function, so I removed it from the function and placed it "outside". It did not work.
2. Since I set the `p` with the class `.desc`, I figured I would have to use `$.each`.

**I wrote:**

```
var desc = $('.desc')
desc.each(function() {
  $(this).text(desc.text().substring(0,250) + '...');
  console.log("work");
});
```

Returned duplicate data.

3. I figured maybe because it's a class so I switched to `#desc`. changed to `jobDetail.setAttribute('class', 'desc')` and called `$('#desc')` It worked by would randomly limit only a few `p` but not all.

**Questions:** How can I properly limit the content length of my `p` and add an ellipses in my JSON function?

**Complete Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Create variable to append postings to
var postingsContainer = document.querySelector('div.job-container');

// Creates postings JSON request
$.getJSON('https://api.smartrecruiters.com/v1/companies/SynchronyGroup/postings', function (postings) {

    // Check to see if data is being pulled
    //console.log(postings);

    showJobs(postings);


});

// Function that pulls json data and populates careers section
function showJobs(jsonObj) {

    // Variable that holds job postings json data
    var jobs = jsonObj['content']

    // Loop to create open position elements
    for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {

        // Creates Column for job postings
        var jobPosting = document.createElement('div');
        jobPosting.setAttribute('class', 'col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-5 job-posting');

        // Creates Job Title
        var jobH5 = document.createElement('h5');
        jobH5.textContent = jobs[i].name;

        jobPosting.appendChild(jobH5);
        postingsContainer.appendChild(jobPosting);

        // Store job post IDs in var
        var jobId = jobs[i].ref;

        //
        //
        // IIFE
        (function (jobPosting) {
            // Creates post 2nd ID JSON request
            $.getJSON(jobId, function (data) {

                // Check to see if data is being pulled
                console.log(data);

                showDetails(data, jobPosting);
            })
        }(jobPosting));

    }
}

//Function for posting description and apply url
function showDetails(data, jobPosting) {

    // Creates Company Desc. and Apply Link
    var jobDetail = document.createElement('p');
    var jobApply = document.createElement('a');

    // Pulls job description data and strips HTML Markup
    jobDesc = data.jobAd.sections.jobDescription.text.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');

    jobDetail.setAttribute('class', 'desc')
    jobDetail.textContent = jobDesc;

    jobApply.setAttribute('href', data.applyUrl);
    jobApply.setAttribute('class', 'btn-primary');
    jobApply.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    jobApply.textContent = 'Apply for Position'

    jobPosting.appendChild(jobDetail);
    jobPosting.appendChild(jobApply);

    var desc = $('.desc')
    desc.each(function() {
        $(this).text(desc.text().substring(0,250) + '...');
        console.log("work");
    });

}
```

});

Comment: @Andreas wow...that simple huh Well, it worked. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for:

```
var desc = $('.desc')
desc.each(function() {
    $(this).text(desc.text().substring(0,250) + '...');
    console.log("work");
});
```

Just do:

```
jobDetail.textContent = jobDesc.substr(0, 250) + "..."
```